# Python-telegram-bot stops reading specific commands

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

After my python-telegram-bot runs for a while (and after extensive use) it stops reacting to the `/start` command. It just doesn't read it (see image below).
Then it takes a certain amount of time, before it works again. (Restarting the bot doesn't help, I just have to wait for an hour or so.)

Where could this come from?
It's really strange since any Message or command is read by the bot, except for the `/start` command.

See this Image:

[image: see this Image:]

I enabled debug logging but couldn't find anything obvious. During the call to `get_updates()`, in fact, it logs "No new updates found", although the `/start` command apparently wasn't read.

I'm using PTB v20.8

Here is the code where I initialize the ConversationHandler.

```
def init_application(self):
    # Create the Application and pass it bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token(self.BOTTOKEN).read_timeout(10).get_updates_read_timeout(50).build()
    
    # Add conversation handler with the states 
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", self.start)],
        states={
            self.MENURESPONSE:    [MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^.*$"), self.menu_response)],
            self.TICKETING:       [MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^.*$"), self.ticketing)],
            self.TICKETING_CHECK: [MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^.*$"), self.ticketnumber_check)],
            self.ACCOMMODATION:   [MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^.*$"), self.accommodation)],
            self.PAYMENT:         [MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^.*$"), self.payment)],
            self.BANKING:         [MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^.*$"), self.banking)],
            self.BANKINGUPLOAD:   [MessageHandler(filters.Document.ALL, self.banking_file_upload)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", self.cancel)],
    )
    #application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Document.ALL, self.banking_file_upload))
    application.add_handler(conv_handler)
    self.application = application
    return
```

If I rename the command `/start` to something else, for example `/start2`, and I restart my bot, then I can use my app, and everything is fine.
Still, it doesn't read the `/start` command, but everything works. After about an hour or so, it starts to read the `/start` command again.

Comment: Could you share the code at least about the /start-command? Hard to debug otherwise. Also, you say it's after extensive use. Maybe some of the other commands is hanging it.

Comment: Added the code where I initialize the ConversationHandler

Comment: Wait, this part `filters.Regex("^.*$")` kind of looks like you are running all the commands for all possible messages. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes, I turned them all off, since my start command returns self.MENURESPONSE, so the conversation continues there. Generally, I'm evaluating user respoonses inside the individual functions, and depending on what the user says, I return for example either self.TICKETING or self.ACCOMMODATION, and the interaction continues there.
I thought this is the intended way to do it?